# Как составить возможные комбинации между элементами множеств?

Tags: множества, c++

Как составить возможные комбинации между элементами множеств?

Составить цепочку длинной в количество множеств, в каждую из которых входит по одному элементу из каждого множества.
Все множества целочисленные и значения элементов множеств идут по порядку(0,1,2 и.т.д)

```
enum ПЕРВАЯ 
{
А1,  
А2
};
enum ВТОРАЯ 
{
Б1,    
Б2
};
enum ТРЕТЬЯ 
{
В1,
В2,
В3
};

Чтобы получилось так:
А1 - Б1 - В1
А1 - Б1 - В2
А1 - Б1 - В3

А1 - Б2 - В1
А1 - Б2 - В2
А1 - Б2 - В3

А2 - Б1 - В1
А2 - Б1 - В2
А2 - Б1 - В3

А2 - Б2 - В1
А2 - Б2 - В2
А2 - Б2 - В3

// Допустим данные по всем enum хранятся так
struct МНОЖЕСТВО
{
int первый;
int последний;
};

std::vector<МНОЖЕСТВО> вектор;
вектор.resize(3);

// ПЕРВАЯ
вектор[0].первый = (int)ПЕРВАЯ::А1;
вектор[0].последний = (int)ПЕРВАЯ::А2;

// ВТОРАЯ
вектор[1].первый = (int)ВТОРАЯ::Б1;
вектор[1].последний = (int)ВТОРАЯ::Б2;

// ТРЕТЬЯ
вектор[2].первый = (int)ТРЕТЬЯ::В1;
вектор[2].последний = (int)ТРЕТЬЯ::В3;
```

Каким образом можно получить все комбинации?

---

---

Без 1C style.
Работает только для множеств, где все элементы идут строго по порядку.

```
struct enum_maker
{

struct enum_class
{
int first;
int last;
std::string name;
};

std::vector<enum_class> tree;

void add_enum(int first, int last , std::string name)
{
enum_class enum_ob; 
enum_ob.first = first;
enum_ob.last = last;
enum_ob.name = name;
tree.push_back(enum_ob);
}

void build_tree()
{

int iterations = 1; 
int enums = tree.size();

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.resize(enums);

std::vector<int> elements_in_enum;
for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++)
{
elements_in_enum.push_back((tree[i].last - tree[i].first)+1);
iterations *= elements_in_enum[i];
}

int special_A = iterations;

// заполняем матрицу
for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++)
{
special_A = special_A / elements_in_enum[i];

int count_elements=0;
int current_enum_element = tree[i].first;
for(int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
{
if(count_elements == special_A){current_enum_element++;

if(current_enum_element>tree[i].last)
{
current_enum_element=tree[i].first;
}
count_elements=0;
}
count_elements++;
matrix[i].push_back(current_enum_element);
}
}

for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++)
{
std::cout << "\n\n\n#### I=" << tree[i].name;
for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
{
std::cout << "\nj=" << matrix[i][j] ;
}
}

for(int i = 0; i < matrix[0].size(); i++)
{
std::string pairs;
for(int j = 0; j < tree.size(); j++)
{
pairs += "[" + std::to_string( matrix[j][i]) + "]";
}
std::cout << "\npairs=" << pairs;
}
}

};

enum FIRST {A1,A2,A3,A4}; 
enum SECOND {B1,B2};
enum THIRD {C1,C2,C3};

int main()
{
enum_maker enum_maker_;
enum_maker_.add_enum(FIRST::A1 , FIRST::A4 , "FIRST");
enum_maker_.add_enum(SECOND::B1 , SECOND::B2, "SECOND");
enum_maker_.add_enum(THIRD::C1 , THIRD::C3, "THIRD");

enum_maker_.build_tree();
std::system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Число множеств 3 или неопределённое?
Думаю можно сделать следующим образом, используя двумерную матрицу.
1) посчитать количество возможных итераций как произведения количества элементов в во всех множествах. В Вашем случае 2*2*3 = 12. Значит будет матрица 12Хколичество_множеств = 12х3.

2) Запишем в первый столбец значение А1 12/2 раз и A2 тоже 6 раз.
получим

```
[A1, 0, 0]
... 4 раза то же самое
[A1, 0, 0]
[A2, 0, 0]
... 4 раза то же самое
[A2, 0, 0]
```

Далее второй столбец, циклом два раза так же, то есть чередуем 12/2/2 = по три раза (где первое 2 - число в первом множестве, второе 2 - во втором). Получим b1,b1,b1,b2,b2,b2,b1,b1,b1,b2,b2,b2.

```
[A1, B1, 0]
[A1, B1, 0]
[A1, B1, 0]
[A1, B2, 0]
[A1, B2, 0]
[A1, B2, 0]
[A2, B1, 0]
[A2, B1, 0]
[A2, B1, 0]
[A2, B2, 0]
[A2, B2, 0]
[A2, B2, 0]
```

Таким же способом находим, что третье множество нужно брать по 12/2/2/3 = 1 разу. Получим:

```
[A1, B1, С1]
[A1, B1, С2]
[A1, B1, С3]
[A1, B2, С1]
[A1, B2, С2]
[A1, B2, С3]
[A2, B1, С1]
[A2, B1, С2]
[A2, B1, С3]
[A2, B2, С1]
[A2, B2, С2]
[A2, B2, С3]
```

Имеем все варианты, можно с любым количеством элементов и множеств. Из матрицы не тяжело перегнать в вектор. Я правильно понял, вам это необходимо получить?

Answer (score 7):

Это система счисления с переменной базой.

- Узнаем количество комбинаций как произведение размеров множеств
- Перебираем все комбинации, где номер комбинации идентифицирует номер элемента в каждом множестве.

Реализация на javascript'е (на плюсы переписать, думаю, будет несложно):

```
// Каждое множество - разряд системы счисления,
// для примера десятичная CC
var m = [
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    ];

var mc = 1; // Число комбинаций
for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    mc*=m[i].length;
}

var r = []; // Массив всех комбинаций
for (var j=0;j<mc;j++){ // Номер текущей комбинации
    var cr = [];        // Текущая комбинация
    var nc = 1;         // Сдвиг разрядов
    for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++){         // Бежим по множествам
        var shifted = Math.floor(j / nc); // Номер комбинации, 
                                          // сдвинутый на i разрядов влево.
                                          // Аналог для двоичной системы <<i
        var idx = shifted % m[i].length;  // Индекс элемента в i-том разряде
        cr.push(m[i][idx]); // Заносим в комбинацию элемент по полученному индексу
        nc *= m[i].length;  // Двигаем разряд влево дальше
    }
    r.push(cr); // Заносим комбинацию в массив
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/Cdxak/)

Comment: Тоже такая задача встала. Подкорректировал эту реализаци под Java. Все сходу взлетело. Спасибо.